# How to use 读作 in the sentence "67.5读作六十七点五"?

Tags: usage

In the textbook, I read this: 67.5读作六十七点五.

Question: 
What's the role of 读作？ Why 读作 is there？

谢谢您！

Answer (score 4):

You can replace 读作 with 'read as'

The sentence can be translated as:
  67.5 reads as 六十七点五

Answer (score 1):

Meaning: is read as

e.g. (a number) is read as something.

Reminder:

Don't mix it up with 叫做. 叫做 refers to names, 读作 refers to language.

Comment: ps To be precise, 读作 refers to words or sentences.